# How to play a melody using Tone.js

Tags: tone.js

I have an array of notes like this

```
const notes = [{note: 'C4', duration: '8n'}, {note: 'D4', duration: '4n'}, {note: 'C4', duration: '2n'}, {note: '', duration: '8n'}] //last element stands for a pause
```

How do I play a melody based on this array?
And is there a better way to store a melody?

Or maybe should I use another lib for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I've done it this way:

```
playTab = tab => {
    const now = Tone.Time()
    let currentTime = 0
    tab.forEach(item => {
        const {note, duration} = parseNote(item)
        if (note !== '') {
            this.synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, duration, now + currentTime)
        }
        currentTime += Tone.Time(duration).toSeconds()
    })
}
```

Is it a good decision? Or should it be done differently?